# Uncaught type error & Uncaught reference error while calling EXTJS method from JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

Small part of the XTJS code :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Alarms.Exporter', {
namespace : undefined,
exportMax : undefined,
pdfLink : undefined,
excelLink : undefined,
totalAlarms : 0,
//UI
windowDialog : undefined,

constructor : function(namespace, pdfLink, excelLink,
        exportMax) {
    this.namespace = namespace;
    this.pdfLink = pdfLink;
    this.excelLink = excelLink;
    this.exportMax = exportMax;
},

setTotalAlarms : function(value) {
    this.totalAlarms = value;
},

doExport : function(format) {
    var url = '';
    var totalAlarms = this.totalAlarms;

    if (totalAlarms > this.exportMax) {
        if (this.exportMax != 0) {
            totalAlarms = this.exportMax;
        }
    }

    if (totalAlarms > 0) {
        if (format == 'pdf') {
            url = this.pdfLink;
        } else {
            url = this.excelLink
        }

        this.show(url, totalAlarms);
    } else {
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title : 'Export Alarms',
            msg : 'There are no alarms to export',
            buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
            icon : Ext.Msg.INFO
        });
    }
}
```

});

JSP Code:

Create the object `AlarmsExporter` with a random namespace

```
    if (typeof <%= table.getNamespace() %>AlarmsExporter == 'undefined') {
    <%= table.getNamespace() %>AlarmsExporter = Ext.create('MyApp.Alarms.Exporter', '<%=table.getNamespace()%>', '<%=Util.encodeUrl(request, response, table.getPdfLink())%>', '<%=Util.encodeUrl(request, response, table.getExcelLink())%>', '<%= Util.getNumAlarmsExport()%>');
}
```

Call the ext method `doExport()`

```
            <a href="javascript:<%= table.getNamespace() %>AlarmsExporter.doExport('xls');">
           <img src="<%= xlsIcon %>" alt="Save as Excel Spreadsheet">
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:<%= table.getNamespace() %>AlarmsExporter.doExport('pdf');">
           <img src="<%= pdfIcon %>" alt="Save as PDF"/>
        </a>
```

Now when I'm clicking those link I am getting error that :

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _mo_navigation_WAR_ManagedObjectsPortlets_INSTANCE_Bk8L_AlarmsExporter is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `.js` file which contains the `extjs` code is either missing or not reachable from your JSP. Check in the `JSP` that are you including the `.js` or the path is correct or not.

I believe this should fix your problem.